# Is it possible to accelerate data copying between tables?

Tags: mysql

I came across the question of optimizing data copying between tables. The task is to copy data from one table to another table within the same database. The classic approach using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` takes too much time because the source table contains a large amount of data.

Since the current query takes several hours, I would like to find a way to substantially accelerate the execution of the operation.

Are there any techniques or methods to accelerate this process? Perhaps there are certain database settings or alternative SQL queries that can help to speed up the data copying process?

Any suggestions or insights would be highly appreciated.

*Current query*

```sql
INSERT INTO B
SELECT
       id,
       col1,
       col2,
       day,
       ...
FROM A
WHERE day = '2023-08-14' AND col1 IN (
       SELECT col1 FROM C WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
);
```

*Explain*

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | INSERT | B | null | ALL | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| 1 | SIMPLE | C | null | range | col_1 | col_1 | 9 | null | 14604 | 100 | Using where; Using index; Start temporary |
| 1 | SIMPLE | A | null | ref | ci1 | ci1 | 40 | const | 146884 | 10 | Using where; End temporary |

*Тable А* - 300 million records

```sql
create table A
(
    id    int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    day   char(10)                       not null,
    col_1  varchar(32)                    null,
    col_2  varchar(48)                    null,
    col_3  varchar(48)                    null,
    col_4  varchar(128)                   null,
    col_5  varchar(48)      default ''    null,
    col_6  varchar(32)                    null,
    col_7  char(2)          default 'NA'  not null,
    col_8  varchar(256)                   not null,
    col_11 int unsigned                   not null,
    col_12 int unsigned     default '0'   not null,
    col_13 int unsigned     default '0'   not null,
    col_14 int unsigned     default '0'   not null,
    col_15 decimal(12, 3)   default 0.000 not null,
    col_16 decimal(12, 3)   default 0.000 not null,
    col_17 decimal(12, 3)   default 0.000 not null,
    col_18 decimal(12, 3)   default 0.000 not null,
    col_19 decimal(12, 3)   default 0.000 not null,
    col_20 tinyint unsigned default '50'  not null,
    col_21 tinyint unsigned default '0'   not null,
    col_9  tinyint unsigned default '1'   not null,
    col_22 tinyint unsigned default '0'   not null
) collate = utf8mb4_general_ci;

create index ci1
    on A (day, col_6, col_9);
```

*Table B* - 30 million records

```sql
create table B
(
    id    int unsigned           not null primary key,
    day   char(10)               not null,
    col_1  varchar(32)            null,
    col_2  varchar(48)            null,
    col_3  varchar(48)            null,
    col_4  varchar(128)           null,
    col_5  varchar(48) default '' null,
    col_6  varchar(32)            null,
    col_7  char(2)                not null,
    col_8  varchar(256)           not null,
    col_9  tinyint unsigned       not null,
    col_10 tinyint unsigned       null
) collate = utf8mb4_general_ci;

create index ci1
    on B (day, col_1, col_6, col_9);

create index col10
    on B (col_10);

create index day_col1
    on B (day, col_1);
```

*Table С* - 100 thousand records

```
create table C
(
    id    int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    col_1 bigint unsigned null,
    constraint col_1
        unique (col_1)
) collate = utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

Comment: First of all, you need to determine if the problem is with the SELECT query or inserting into the destination. Try `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE ...` to see how long that takes.

Comment: Try to avoid `WHERE col1 IN (SELECT ...)` queries, MySQL doesn't implement this well. Use `WHERE EXISTS (...)` or `JOIN`.

Comment: You could remove all indexes before the query, and add them later again.

Comment: I assume you mean remove all indexes from the destination table @Evert